# List of uninteresting words

Tags: nlp, text-processing, stop-words

[Caveat] This is not directly a programing question, but it is something that comes up so often in language processing that I'm sure it's of some use to the community.

Does anyone have a good list of *uninteresting* (English) words that have been tested by more then a casual look? This would include all prepositions, conjunctions, etc... words that may have semantic meaning, but are often frequent in *every* sentence, regardless of the subject. I've built my own lists from time to time for personal projects but they've been ad-hoc; I continuously add words that I forgotten as they come in.

Comment: Now that I know the magic phrase is "stop-words" I've been able to find a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218335/stop-words-list-for-english. However, I searched in vain before I posted - I'll leave it to those with more SO knowledge to decide to close this or not. Perhaps my phrasing will have luck for a future search?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These words are usually called [stop words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words). The Wikipedia article contains much more information about them, including where to find some lists.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean [stop words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words).

There's a few links to lists of stop words on Wikipedia, including [this one](http://armandbrahaj.blog.al/2009/04/14/list-of-english-stop-words/).