# List of stopwords for NLP

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval, lda, topic-modeling, wsd

Is there a list of stop words that people usually use to remove punctuations and close class words (such as `he, she, it`) when performing NLP or IR/IE related task?

I have been trying out topic modeling using gibbs sampling for word sense disambiguation and it keeps giving punctuations and close class words high probabilities just because they appear frequently in the corpus. https://github.com/christianscheible/BNB/blob/master/nb_gibbs.py

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try googling? The top hits I get either contain stopword lists or are stack overflow posts that link to said lists:

- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218335/stop-words-list-for-english)
- [and here](http://www.ranks.nl/resources/stopwords.html)
- [and here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html)